# how to check whene and who deleted a file in win7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, user-accounts, logfiles

A program and its dependencies got deleted from my computer without my knowledge and consent, probably via the guest session.

are there any records in windows 7 of deleted files,
the time of deletion, and the user who deleted them?

Comment: This information isn't logged unless it's turned on.  It is not enabled by default, so what you want to know, is not possible given your configuration